# Which is the correct way to Get & Set data (not state/props) without re-render React component?

Tags: reactjs, recursion

Let's say I have a `<RecursiveTree />` component.

```
function List({ node }) {
  // I want to add node.id to an visited array for querying.
  if (visited.includes(node.child)) return null; // stop recursion

  setVisited([...visited, node.id]) // Add to visited 

  return <List node={node.child} />;
}

function RecursiveTree({ data }) {
  // state/props causes re-render.
  const [visited, setVisited] = useState([]);

  return <List node={data} visited={visited} setVisted={setVisited} />;
}
```

I want to add **nodeId** to `visited[]` (conditionally) when child node render.

How do I add (w/o `setVisited`). and get `visited[]` (w/o passing as props)?

**Updated:**

Ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables

Comment: Can you proved more information here? Including relevant code from your component. How/where is `visited` stored?

Comment: Is the issue here that with the current structure, when the `List` element renders, it adds the `node.id` to the `visited` array and then immediately unmounts, so that quickly no `List` elements are rendered?

Comment: No, it creates infinite loop because `<RecursiveTree />` re-render by setVisited is called by each child component.

Comment: Hmm that might be caused by your check to stop recursion, should maybe be: `if (visited.includes(node.child.id))`?

Comment: Seem like you misunderstood. What I need is a context to access and update `visited` during the recursion, I can't to use state/props because it causes re-render. I can't also use react context due to unable to update. My temporary solution is passing getter/setter functions as props, but I think it's not the recommended way.

Comment: Updating context will also cause components to re-render. Passing down a callback function to a child is a fine way to do things. I think you just need a better way to stop recursion, possibly related to my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save data without re-render you should use a `useRef` for example and use it in `RecursiveTree`

```
const List = ({ node, setVisited, visited }) => {
  if (visited.includes(node.id)) return null;

  useEffect(() => {
    setVisited(node.id);
  },[]);

//...
};

const RecursiveTree = ({ data }) => {
  const visited = useRef([]);

  const setVisited = id => {
    visited.current.push(id);
  };

  return <List node={data} visited={visited.current} setVisted={setVisited} />;
};
```

Comment: Cool, ref & useRef are what I need. Thanks!